# ¿Como hago que el focus de mi TextField siempre este al final del mismo

Tags: java, javafx

Hola tengo un codigo el cual despues de darle a cierto boton se escribe cosas en el texField pero cuando el texto que se escribe es mayor que el tamaño del texField sale el Scroll pero el focus es al principio, entonces cada vez que le doy al boton tengo que bajar abajo para ver lo nuevo que se ha escrito, alguna solucion para que el focus sea abajo y no al principio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método `setCaretPosition` para poner la posición dentro del `JTextsField` de tal forma que sea la última posición del campo de texto, como se indica en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
JTextField campoTexto = new JTextField();
// ...
campoTexto.AddFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        String texto = campoTexto.getText();
        if (texto != null)
            campoTexto.setCaretPosition(texto.legth());
    }
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {}
});
```

Ten en cuenta que el argumento debe estar en rango [0, campo.getText().length()] o saltará una excepción de tipo `IllegalArgumentException`.

**Edición**

Investigando en la [documentación de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#positionCaret-int-) se puede encontrar el método análogo para JavaFX: `positionCaret`, que funciona de forma similar al de Java Swing.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero necesito la solucion en javaFx, y ese metodo no existe en el TextField de javaFX :(

Comment: @ErnestoDavidOlivaPerez disculpa, no me fijé bien que era JavaFX y puse el de Java Swing, pero en definitiva son casi lo mismo.